# Python: NameError name '[input]' is not defined

Tags: python, undefined, nameerror

I'm trying to make a simple little tool for converting inches to centimeters and am stuck at trying to take a user input ('y' or 'n') for deciding whether to do another conversion or terminate. Here's what I've done:

```
import time

def intro():
    print "Welcome! This program will convert inches to centimeters for you.\n"
    convert()

def convert():
    input_cm = input(("Inches: "))
    inches_conv = input_cm * 2.54
    print "Centimeters: %f\n" % inches_conv
    time.sleep(3)
    restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
    if restart == 'y':
        convert()
    elif restart == 'n':
        end_fast()
    else:
        print "I didn't quite understand that answer. Terminating."
        end_slow()

def end_fast():
    print "This program will close in 5 seconds."
    time.sleep(5)

def end_slow():
    print "This program will close in 30 seconds."
    time.sleep(30)

intro()
```

And this results in:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Sam\Programming\Python\the hard way\ex5.4.py", line 29, in 
>       intro()
>     File "C:\Users\Sam\Programming\Python\the hard way\ex5.4.py", line 5, in intro
>       convert()
>     File "C:\Users\Sam\Programming\Python\the hard way\ex5.4.py", line 12, in convert
>       restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no?\n"))
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Help appreciated.

Comment: Use `raw_input` not `input`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that is an answer, by the way :)

Comment: That did indeed fix it Ashwini. Many thanks!

Comment: I did, it's just it was under the time limit if I recall correctly. I bookmarked it so that I could come back and accept it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of `input` try `raw_input`:

replace:

```
restart = str(input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: "))
```

on:

```
restart = raw_input("Do you wish to make another conversion? [y]Yes or [n]no: ")
```